# confusion regarding Thread.Join

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing

I have a very little confusion regarding `Thread.Join()` method. I have seen [THIS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95hbf2ta(v=vs.110).aspx) MSDN post and few SO posts, but couldn't clear this confusion.

In case of multiple threads, does it wait for all threads to complete? or blocks the execution of next thread until first has completed? Suppose following scenario:

```
List<Thread> myThreads = new List<Threads>();
while(someCondition == true)
{
   Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate 
                {
                    processSomeCalculations(x, y);
                })); 
    thread.Start();
    myThreads.Add(thread);

}

foreach (Thread thread in myThreads)
{
   thread.Join();
}

Print("all threads completed now");
```

In above scenario, when `thread.Join()` is called for first item of list (i.e, first thread of list), `does it mean that thread 2 (i.e, the second thread of the list) can NEVER continue its execution, until first thread has been completed?`

OR

Does this mean, `all the threads in the list will continue execution in PARALLEL manner, and PRINT method will be called after all threads have finished execution?`

*Summary of my question:* In above scenario, would all the threads will continue execution in PARALLEL? or They will execute one by one, after 1st has finished execution?

Comment: Why don't you write the code to test this?

Answer (score 3):

It's the latter, it will simply block execution on the main thread until all of the threads you've spawned have finished execution, or in this case finished with `processSomeCalculations(x, y)`, and then print `"all threads completed now"`.

Answer (score 2):

As jacob already said, it's the latter.
In addition, you can think of your code as the following:

1.) Start multiple threads

2.) Then inside your loop: Take the first thread from the list and block the main thread until the first thread has finished. Only the main thread (i.e., the thread that called `.Join()`) gets blocked, all other threads continue.

3 ... n.) Again inside loop: Take the next thread and block main thread until this one has finished (or just continue if thread already finished)

After the loop you can be sure that all threads have finished.

Comment: so it means, in case of my scenario, if I call `thread.Join` right after `thread.start()` inside the loop, (instead of a foreach loop as i did after while loop) it would have the same effect?

Comment: No, in that case you would 1. Start the first thread 2. Wait until the first thread finished 3. Start the second thread 4. Wait until the second thread has finished 5. ...
The thread that calls `myThread.Join()` is blocked until `myThread` finished.